# Understanding the dimension of a particular subspace in Linear Algebra in C³

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am having trouble to determine the dimension of the subspace of T.
How is it done, when there is just one vector given?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $T$ is the span of the vector $(0, i, 2)$, so the dimension is 1.